# Why is this line throwing an error with a conditional present?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Why does this line throw an error:

```
 return if self.is_a? FeatureArticle || self.is_a? BracketArticle
```

It works if I do just

```
return if self.is_a? FeatureArticle
```

Or if I do

```
return if self.is_a? BracketArticle
```

Error message:

[image]

Already tried using `if...return...end`, using parentheses, `return false if ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser is lost in that case and is evaluating the expression differently because it takes first: `FeatureArticle || self.is_a? BracketArticle` as the argument of `self.is_a?`

Then, it evaluates `FeatureArticle || self.is_a? BracketArticle` into `FeatureArticle || self.is_a?` which returns `true/false` and `BracketArticle`. You end up having:

`true/false BracketArticle`

which is an invalid expression. and that makes real sense. when you use logical operators, you should be clear about the operands of the operator by using brackets.
A quick example of how things can be twisted:
If you have `x`, `y` and `z`, such that: `x = true`, `y = false`, `z = false`

```
>> x #=> true
>> y #=> false
>> z #=> false
>> x || y && z #=> true #=> true
>> x || (y && z) #=> true #=> true
>> (x || y) && z #=> false #=> false
```

Comment: Nice! I figured it was something like that, but I wasn't sure so I just removed it haha.

Comment: Are you saying that `self.is_a? FeatureArticle || self.is_a? BracketArticle` is parsed as `self.is_a?((FeatureArticle || self.is_a?) BracketArticle)`? If so, why would Ruby do that considering that `is_a?` has a required argument?

Comment: Yes. the required argument is there: `FeatureArticle || self.is_a? BracketArticle`. 
The problem comes at the end when you end up with an expression that looks like this:
`false BracketArticle` or `true BracketArticle`, which is invalid.
The expression is ambiguous and I proved that with the `x, y, z` example above.

Answer (score 3):

```
return if self.is_a?(FeatureArticle) || self.is_a?(BracketArticle)
```

I don't know the exact reasoning behind it, but it's just how Ruby parses its code.

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
```

tl;dr just do regular function call rather than implicit parentheses

Answer (score 1):

[TedTran2019's answer is very good.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58981066/111363) In general, the best ruby codebases I've seen use explicit parenthesis except when there is no argument or when there is a strong convention of omitting parens for that particular usage.

Another way to write your method would be:

```
# Match exact classes (not descendants)
return if [FeatureArticle, BracketArticle].member?(self.class)
```

[Enumerable#member?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-member-3F)

Comment: Suppose `class A; end; class B; end; class C < B; def m; is_a?(A) || is_a?(B); end; end`. Then `C.new.m #=> true`, because `C.new.is_a?(B) #=> true`. If we change the definition of `C` to `class C < B; def m; [A, B].member?(self.class);end; end`, then  `C.new.m #=> false`, because `self.class #=> C`. Your comment about matching exact classes shows you understand the distinction, so why are you suggesting the use of `member?` when it gives results that differ from those obtained by using `is_a?`? Note one could use the old-fashioned `Array#include?` in place of `member?`.

Answer (score 0):

Following Gilg Him's answer, the only thing left to explain then, is this behavior:

1. `false || self.is_a? --> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))` and
2. `false || self.is_a? String --> SyntaxError ((irb):14: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input)`
3. `true || self.is_a? --> true`. Implying that it doesn't evaluate the right side at all in this case. But,
4. `true || self.is_a? String --> SyntaxError ((irb):14: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input)`

I guess it means the presence of an `||` makes it expect `expression || expression` and instead it's `expression || expression CONSTANT`, raising a `SyntaxError` right off the bat.

Otherwise we would be able to get to `return if self.is_a? true BracketArticle --> TypeError (class or module required)`

Would love any further elaboration on this!